# Is there a WordPress hook that fires before post.php, from which I can get the post ID?

Tags: wordpress, hook

I have appointment software and the client data sheets are a custom post type in WordPress. The service provider role cannot read those client data sheets, except when the admin makes an appointment, because at that time the post author for the client sheet is changed to be the user ID of the service provider, which allows them to read and edit their client. But if another appointment is made for that client with a different provider, the first provider loses those rights and gets "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this item."

I need to hook before the following code runs in post.php, currently line 138
`if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) { wp_die( __( 'Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this item.' ) ); }`

I have a custom function that amends the author ID. It needs the post ID of the client sheet the user is trying to access.

I tried hooking into `load-post.php` but no arguments are passed.

I tried hooking `add_meta_boxes` but it fires after post.php executes `wp_die()`

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'check_user_cap', 10, 2 );
function check_user_cap($post_type, $post){
// this function is never called, but I would do something like...
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) ) {
    if ( verify_provider_against_client($post->ID ) ){
         $addr = get_bloginfo( 'url' ).'/wp-admin/post.php?post='.$post->ID.'&action=edit';
         wp_redirect( $addr );
         wp_die();
    }
}
```

Can I filter current_user_can()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this hook `user_has_cap` [Click Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/)

You can use this hook to check capabilities as below

```php
<?php 
add_filter('user_has_cap', 'custom_user_capabilities_check', 10, 4);

function custom_user_capabilities_check($allcaps, $caps, $args, $user) {
    // Check if the current operation is 'edit_post'
    if (isset($args[0]) && $args[0] === 'edit_post') {
        $post_id = $args[2];

        // Check if the user doesn't have the 'edit_post' capability
        if (!isset($allcaps['edit_post']) || !$allcaps['edit_post']) {
            // Check if the user has a custom capability (e.g., 'edit_client_sheet')
            if (current_user_can('edit_client_sheet', $post_id)) {
                // Grant the 'edit_post' capability dynamically
                $allcaps['edit_post'] = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $allcaps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final function I used:

```
function custom_user_capabilities_check($allcaps, $caps, $args, $user) {
// Check if the current operation is 'edit_post'
if (isset($args[0]) && $args[0] === 'edit_post') {
    $post_id = $args[2];
    $type = get_post_type($post_id);
    switch ($type){
        case 'custom_post_type':
        case 'custom_post_type2':
            if ( ! isset($allcaps['edit_others_custom_post_types'])){
                    
                if (ensure_provider($post_id, $user->ID)){
                    $allcaps['edit_others_custom_post_types'] = true;
                    $allcaps['edit_published_custom_post_types'] = true;
                    return $allcaps;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 'custom_post_type3':
            if ( ! isset($allcaps['edit_others_custom_post_type3'])){
               if (ensure_provider($post_id, $user->ID)){
                    $allcaps['edit_custom_post_type3'] = true;
                    $allcaps['edit_published_custom_post_type3'] = true;
                    return $allcaps;
               }
           }
           break;               
      }
  }
  return $allcaps;
}
```